# How To Fetch Specific Column From Repository Using Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have problem about to fetching some specific column on Java Spring.
I am using Java Spring Boot and GraphDB as my database and I use Model and Repository to access the database (ex: I have userRepository, and I use userRepository.FindAll and all records are loaded within all their fields).
For Instance, I have a table with column/field:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId 
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String role;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean active;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName,
            String lastName, String role, Boolean active) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

With Repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

}
```

I didn't put UserRepository.FindAll because it already implement it on GraphRepository

I don't need to load "Password" field. What should I do to load the record without load the "Password" field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class annotated with [@QueryResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult)

```
@QueryResult
public class UserSimple {
    String username;
    String role;
}
```

In UserRepository interface:

```
@Query("MATCH (u:USER) RETURN u.username as username, u.role as role")
List<UserSimple> findAllSimple();
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult

**EDIT:** (answers to questions in comments)

These classes annotated with @QueryResult can easily be inner classes, it is really up to you.

To return the graph id use `ID(u) as id` in the return clause.

Comment: You say that I need to create class with @QueryResult. And as I know, 1 class = 1 file class. Do I have to create many file if I need many query like this?

Comment: Can I pass the id?
@Query("MATCH (u:USER) RETURN u.id as id, u.username as username, u.role as role")
I cannot fetch id